# BluezでJust Workのペアリングを受け付ける方法

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez

Raspberry PiにBluetoothドングルをつけて、スマホからペアリングをしようとしています。
デフォルトの設定だと、スマホ側からRaspberry Piにペアリングを要求すると、PINコードが表示されてYes/Noをクリックしないとペアリングできません。
Raspberry PiのBluezの設定を変えて、スマホのペアリング要求があったとき、Yes/NoのクリックなしでペアリングするにはBluezのどこの設定を変えればいいでしょうか？
hcid.confのsecurityをnoneにすればいいのでしょうか？